# Weather sensors required for ILS approach operations?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

Was flying into Sullivan County this weekend and had to run the RNAV instead of the ILS. ATC advised there was a NOTAM for the weather sensors (which we had already confirmed.) Does an ILS approach require that the airport have functioning weather or is this just a case of a 2-for-1?

Comment: Weather sensors were out so you couldn't get winds & ceiling?

Comment: @CrossRoads yeah, was advised not to trust information on the ATIS frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not an ILS may be conducted without proper weather reporting will depend on the regulations under which the flight is operated.

In simple terms, a flight operated under 14 CFR 91 may perform an ILS without this weather reporting.

This may also be allowed under the eligible-on-demand rules of 14 CFR 135, if all pertinent requirements are met.

Otherwise, a flight operated under 14 CFR 135 or 14 CFR 121 will generally not be approved to conduct an ILS without approved weather reporting.

This answer applies under FAA jurisdiction.